# Rails acts_as_tenant - access current tenant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added the gem 'acts_as_tenant' to my Rails app.

I have set the following in the application controller:

```
  set_current_tenant_by_subdomain(:tenant, :subdomain)
```

I have also added columns of information to the Tenants table.  For instance the statuscode_id for a 'closed' status.  In the Request model, I would like to scope using that column.

Something like this:

```
scope :closed, where(:statuscode_id => Tenant.find(current_tenant.id).request_closed)
```

But, `current_tenant` isn't working.

What can I use to get the id of the current tenant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've done so far is say that the subdomain will be used to define the tenant.  In order to restrict the tenant to only see their data you need to define this in the model.

You need to add `acts_as_tenant(:tenant)` to your `Request` model.  You will also need a `tenant_id` column in the database for this table.

Once you've done this, the gem will take care of the rest and all your database access will automatically take care of restricting access by tenant.  e.g. `Request.all` will use default scope behind the scenes to restrict to only the requests owned by that tenant.

Please see [ErwinM/acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) for more information on this.

Comment: I already have the `acts_as_tenant(:tenant) to my Request model. I also have a tenant_id column in the database for this table`. But, the Tenant table does not have `acts_as_tenant`. And I'm trying to set a scope based on information in the current Tenant record.

Comment: Sorry @Reddirt, I just reread your original question again.  Instead of `current_tenant`, try `ActsAsTenant.current_tenant`.

Comment: No problem!  But, I have a follow-up question if it's OK.  Locally I'm using POW. I have now loaded the app to Heroku and I'm getting this `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:310:in `find_with_ids': Couldn't find Tenant without an ID (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)` Is there anything special I need to do to have it work on Heroku?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Heroku.  Try posting a new question and hopefully someone can help.

Comment: PS - I need to use `ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.id`